# How to change CSS using an array on each Royal Slider switch

Tags: jquery, arrays, slider

I'm working on changing the color of an HTML block each time a slide switches over. I'm using [RoyalSlider](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/royal-slider/documentation/), and I have 5 colors that I would like to cycle through, in order.

My current effort looks like this:

```
    // initialize slider
    var sliderInstance = $('#new-royalslider-1').data('royalSlider');

    // bind the rsBeforeAnimStart event
    sliderInstance.ev.on('rsBeforeAnimStart', function() {

        var colors = ["#000000","#464646","#999999"];

        for(var i=0; i<colors.length; i++) {
          $(".color-block").css('background', colors[i]);
        }

    });
```

With this setup, I only get the #999999 value to come up instead of cycling through the array with each slide change. [Here](http://c41media.com.previewdns.com/projects/) is the site that I'm working in, just for context.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks in advance for any help! I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the index of the current slide, we can cycle through the colours upon the animation changing.

```
// initialize slider and define colours
var sliderInstance = $('#new-royalslider-1').data('royalSlider'),
    colors = ["#000000","#464646","#999999"];

// bind the rsBeforeAnimStart event
sliderInstance.ev.on('rsBeforeAnimStart', function() {
    $(".color-block").css('background', colors[sliderInstance.currSlideId % colors.length]);
});
```

Comment: Great! That did it. Thank you for the quick help! For people referencing this later on - change the variable sliderInstance to slider, or the other way around, to make them match up. Thanks again, Richard!

Comment: Thanks @yulichka, I've updated it to reflect the proper object name.